# Merge wifi, wireless-network and wireless-networking tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

How should we handle these tags:

- [wifi](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) 170x
- [wireless-network](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless-network) 16x
- [wireless-networking](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking) 8x

Should they be merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've merged all three into [wi-fi](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wi-fi) since it seems to be "more correct" with the hyphen.

Answer (score 4):

BlueTooth is wireless, but it isn't wifi.

Depending on the use, I could see wireless-network and wireless-networking merged, but Wifi is a specific type of wireless technology.

Grammatically, "wireless-networking" refers to the concept or practice, and "wireless-network" refers to a implemented instance. But I doubt those subtleties are present...

Comment: +1 for "I doubt those subtleties are present"

Comment: I expect that after reviewing [tag:wireless-network] and [tag:wireless-networking] the vast majority of the questions can be moved to [tag:wifi] with maybe a couple for Bluetooth or otherwise not taggable as "wifi". But I agree that wireless-network and wireless-networking can probably be merged.

Comment: @AlEverett I retagged the minority that didn't fit in.  I think we should be good to merge all three tags.